# Form Validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The validation code that i have on my page is:

```
function validateForm() {
    with (document.contactform) {
        var alertMsg = "The following REQUIRED fields\nhave been left empty:\n";
        if (name.value == "") alertMsg += "\nName";
        if (email.value == "") alertMsg += "\nEmail";
        if (message.value == "") alertMsg += "\nMessage";
        if (alertMsg != "The following REQUIRED fields\nhave been left empty:\n") {
            alert(alertMsg);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also i have added the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` into my form section and nothing seems to be working. you can view the source page at http://obliqueinteractive.com/contact.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: please put your code in code tags. Because it's html/javascript we cannot see it. I would edit but don't have enough recognition

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<form id="contactform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="" method="post">
```

to

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="" method="post">
```

The problem occurs when you try to access `document.contactform`. It's looking for a `form` named `contactform`, not a form with an `id` of `contactform`.

Comment: I'd keep the `id="contactform"` -- although adding the `name` attribute fixes the problem, removing the `id` may affect the CSS styling of the form.

Comment: A smart way to solve the problem. Without the need to change js file.

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion is try to use document.getElementById("contactform") instead of just document.contactform

I have never used the with command so I am not exactly sure how it is used

{EDIT}

After playing around on your site I believe what I have suggested will fix your problem,
let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Add `name="contactform"` attribute to the form tag or use   `document.getElementById("contactform")`
instead of `document.contactform`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the **validateForm** function.

change:

```
function validateForm() {
    with (document.contactform) {
```

to:

```
function validateForm() {
    with (document.getElementById('contactform')) {
```